# Authentication as a service to expose rest server to external services

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

I have a rest service which I'd like to expose to other companies' backend services. I already have Firebase which allows authentication but this is for an end user rather than external service.

Is there something similar to Firebase but for service to service communication where 3rd party users can manage keys?

Google Cloud Platform is preferable. I looked at Apigee from Google but it's heavyweight for just authentication.

Comment: Are you trying to authenticate clients of your REST API using Firebase Auth ? Also which keys are you talking about to manage ?

Comment: In my case the clients are services rather than end users.

Comment: You can create an account for that service and then use Firebase Auth REST API to retrieve ID Tokens for that service using their email n pass and verify it on your main server. (Assuming it's all in 1 Firebase project). Is it something you are looking for ?

Comment: Your question does not have enough details. For example, what do you mean by **3rd party users can manage keys**? There are many techniques to implement service-to-servie authentication. Today, a common method is Signed JWTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints) can be a good start. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authentication-method) are the different authentication methods you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Google's [CAS](https://cloud.google.com/certificate-authority-service) to create a private CA.  Give third parties access to add/rollover certs in your private CA (should be possible, not sure).  Then in your services, you can trust the issuer, namely your private CA. You can also use the certs to do fine-grained authorizations.